# android viewflipper not changing view : HELP ! :)

Tags: android, viewflipper

Im having trouble to make work the viewflipper. I created a xml layout file view_flipper.xml :

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/MainView"  layout="@layout/gallery_1" />

    <include android:id="@+id/SearchView"  layout="@layout/search_internal" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

the layout gallery_1 is just a ListView.
the layout search_internal has an edittext, a button, and a listview.

Im using :

```
 ViewFlipper theFlipper=(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    theFlipper.setDisplayedChild( R.id.SearchView );
```

to change the layout, but its apparently work for the code, but on the display, nothing is happening... Can someone help ?

Here is the code of the layout search_internal :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/SearchBox"
>
<EditText android:text="" 
android:id="@+id/QueryText" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="100px"
></EditText>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/BtnOk" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="@string/searchBtnTxt"
android:clickable="true"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/SearchBox"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_marginBottom="65dip"
android:gravity="top"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: setDisplayedChild usually takes zero based index instead of id of the view, which in your case should be 1.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that I was not using correctly the function setDisplayedChild. setDisplayedChild is zero based index apparently. Sorry.

```
    theFlipper.setDisplayedChild( 0 );
```